# "Death March" projects - any writers apart from Yourdon?

Tags: planning, failure

After digging through Google, it appears that Edward Yourdon has done most of the original writing on this topic.

Are there any other writers who have covered this, or a similar topic, related to project failure?

In order to strive for an objective viewpoint, it would be great to get the opinions of some writers other than Yourdon.

Comment: I am not aware of any books on the subject, but one essay that you might not be aware of is "Why Crunch Mode Doesn't Work".  http://www.igda.org/why-crunch-modes-doesnt-work-six-lessons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a google search on my friend and colleague, Tom DeMarco, and track down his page on the Atlantic System Guild's website. I'm pretty sure that he (perhaps along with Tim Lister) have written about the futility and idiocy of death-march projects... Tom's advice is, basically, "just say no!"

Comment: Wow didn't expect a reply from the author himself! Thanks for the info. I guess I'm most interested in different viewpoints on the analysis of a death-march situation, and the preventative steps which could have been taken by the project leaders from the outset, to avoid such a situation. BTW, do you happen to know of any sources I could go to for detailed case-studies of failed projects?

Comment: Just noticed that Tim Lister was co-author of 'Waltzing with Bears'. Already have that on order. :)